Conditional binary programming
I am currently trying to model the relationship that if the binary variables $b_{it}=0$ and $c_{it}=1$, and for the integer non-negative variable $b^{n}_{i(t-1)}=0$, then the new binary variable $a_{it}$ is equal to 1, in all other cases 0. I came up with the following constraints, but I think they are wrong.
\begin{align}
&a_{it} \leq 1 - b^{n}_{i(t-1)}&&\forall i\in I, t\in \{2,...,T\}\\
&a_{it} \leq 1 - b_{it}&&\forall i\in I, t\in \{2,...,T\}\\
&a_{it} \leq c_{it}&&\forall i\in I, t\in \{2,...,T\}\\
&a_{it} \geq c_{it} + b_{it} + b^{n}_{i(t-1)} - 2&&\forall i\in I, t\in \{2,...,T\}
\end{align}
For all four possible combinations, if $b^{n}_{i(t-1)}=0$, the coding works. But if, for example, $b^{n}_{i(t-1)}=2$, then the construct falls apart with constraint 1. How should I model it instead?

Is $b^n_{i(t-1)}$ nonnegative or unrestricted in sign?

I updated my post.

Suppose $0 \le b^n_{it} \le M^n_{it}$ for some constant $M^n_{it}$.  Introduce binary decision variable $y_{it}$ to indicate whether $b^n_{it} > 0$.  Now impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_{it} \le b^n_{it} &\le M^n_{it} y_{it} \\
a_{it} &\le 1 - b_{it} \\ 
a_{it} &\le c_{it} \\ 
a_{it} &\le 1 - y_{i,t-1} \\ 
a_{it} &\ge (1 - b_{it}) + c_{it} + (1 - y_{i,t-1}) - 2 
\end{align}
The first constraint linearizes $y_{it} \iff b^n_{it}>0$.  The last four constraints linearize $a_{it} \iff (\lnot b_{it} \land c_{it} \land \lnot y_{i,t-1})$.

Thank you very much. I dont know if i am stupid or its to late in germany, but i cant reproduce my case. Assuming $c_{it}=1$, $b_{it}=0$ and $b^n_{it}=0$ too. The first constraint yields $y_{it}=0$, the second one $a_{it}\leq 1$, the third $a_{it}\leq 1$, the fourth $a_{it}\leq 0$ and the fifth $a_{it} \geq (1-0)+1+0-2 =0$. From my understanding, this yields $a_{it}=0$, however i want it to be equal to 1, or am i wrong?

@mingabua It was my error.  I should have had $1-y$ instead of $y$ in the last two constraints, corrected now.
